# How do you run InstaBot.py on OpenShift?

Tags: python, openshift, bots, redhat

To run [InstaBot](https://github.com/instabot-py/instabot.py) locally, you just clone the repo, install the requirements.txt, put in your login credentials in example.py, and run `python example.py`. I do not know how this translates to OpenShift.

Let's say you push your code to your own GitHub repo with the login credentials in environment variables (in an git ignored file). You can set environment variables on the OpenShift dashboard, but where's the part where you specify `python example.py`?

Answer (score 1):

For OpenShift, if `example.py` is a self contained Python web application, then you would need to rename it as `app.py`, or add a `.s2i/environment` file to your repo and in it add:

```
APP_FILE=example.py
```

The script should then ensure it is listening on all interfaces, ie., `0.0.0.0` and not just localhost. It also needs to use port 8080.

With that done, you can then use Python S2I builder process in OpenShift to deploy it. The packages listed in `requirements.txt` will be automatically installed for you.

if not familiar with OpenShift, you might consider reading:

- https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

It is a free download.

For details on the Python S2I builder and what environment variables you can set to customise it, see:

- https://github.com/sclorg/s2i-python-container/tree/master/3.6

Comment: I don't think InstaBot runs on any ports? I don't really understand the source code, but I think it's just an infinite loop making calls to the Instagram API.